# Numeric String (arbitrary size) -> Multiple Integers

Tags: php, mysql, 64-bit, 32-bit, bigint

I'm running into a problem because my database has BIGINT data (64-bit integers) but the version of PHP I'm running is only 32-bit.

So when I pull out value from a table I end up with a numeric string representing a 64-bit integer in base 10.  What I would ideally like to do is use the 64-bit integer as a bitmask.  So I need to go to either two 32-bit integers (one representing the upper part and one the lower part) or a numeric string in base 2.

Problem is I can't just multiply it out because my PHP is only 32-bit.  Am I stuck?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [bit shift operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html) to split the 64-bit integer into two 32-bit integers.  So, you could select:

```
select (myBigIntField & 0xffffffff) as lowerHalf,
       (myBigIntField >> 32) as upperHalf
```

Comment: Oooh, that's beautiful. Why didn't I think of that? Note to self: Don't answer questions directly after getting up. +1

Comment: James, that's brilliant.  Thanks!  Unfortunately I just registered so I don't have any reputation to vote your answer up but it's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

To handle arbitrary size integers, you have two options in PHP: [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) and [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) methods.

I *believe* GMP is more efficient by using some custom resources, while BC uses strings directly.

If you won't be processing too many (thousands or more) of numbers at a time, you may use BC directly.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here:

1. Use either [BCMath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) or [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) if they are included in your PHP installation. Both should provide arbitrary-length integers.
2. Ask the database to convert the integer to a 64-character long bit string instead
3. Write a bignum implementation yourself (more work :-))